# How to get an X from a range (1000, 0) in Django Template when you run through a for loop (0, 1000)?

Tags: django, django-templates

Actually, I run through a regular loop:

```
{% for post in posts %}
And I need here X = 1000 then 999 then 998. 
{% endfor %}
```

How to do it? Do you have any ideas?
I tried:

```
{% with x=1000 %}
    {% for post in posts %}            
        {{ x|add:"-1" }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

But it doesn't save that x. It shows 999 each time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try it by creating a  custom **simpletag** that takes **context object**.